# Why do I get this error: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a customlist that has images and text. When I run the app it works, but when I scroll up and down it crahes and gives me the following errors:

```
11-19 17:48:09.530 10113-10113/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=7; index=7
11-19 17:48:09.530 10113-10113/com.example.hadi.do2get E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.hadi.do2get.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.java:39)
```

Heres is the customlistadapter class:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private final Activity context;
private final String[] itemname;
private final Integer[] imgid;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomListAdapter(Activity context, String[] itemname, Integer[] imgid) {
    super(context, R.layout.mylist, itemname);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context=context;
    this.itemname=itemname;
    this.imgid=imgid;
}

public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylist, null);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    TextView extratxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtTitle.setText(itemname[position]);
    imageView.setImageResource(imgid[position]); //this is line 39
    extratxt.setText("Description "+itemname[position]);
    return view;

 };
}
```

And this is the class where the list is:

```
public class Forside extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
EditText filterText;

ImageButton sog;
EditText sogefelt;

static String [] annoncer = {"Hjælp til valutaprogram", "Renovering af kontor", "Fix af computer",
        "Tegner til byggeprojekt", "Statsborgerskab", "Sushi til 100 mennesker", "Bil råd", "Finansiel rådgivning"};
static  Integer[] imageId = {
        R.drawable.it,
        R.drawable.renovering,
        R.drawable.it,
        R.drawable.renovering,
        R.drawable.statsborgerskab,
        R.drawable.sushi,
        R.drawable.bil
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_forside);

    filterText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);
    ListView itemList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);

    listAdapter = new CustomListAdapter (this, annoncer, imageId);
    sog = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sog);
    sog.setOnClickListener(this);
    sogefelt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sogefelt);

    itemList.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    itemList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}


public void onClick (View v){
    if (v == sog){
        String søgeord = sogefelt.getText().toString();
        ArrayList<String> resultater = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String i: annoncer) {
            if (i.contains(søgeord))
                resultater.add(i);
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Sogeresultater.class);
        intent.putExtra("søg", resultater.toArray(new String[resultater.size()]));
        startActivity(intent);
    }

 }
}
```

All the images are PNG

PS: I've searched on Google and here on Stackoverflow for a similar problem/question but the didn't find a solution

Comment: Both `annoncer` and `imageId` size is different. use same size Array to fix this issue

Comment: But they've to be different in my program?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : Why can't they be different?

Comment: Have solved the problem by adding an image more :) So yes, the array annoncer was bigger.